Testing Routes with Spring Boot und JUnit
Hello I really need help testing my routes (if that is even a good practice).
Setup:

Spring Boot
JUnit
Vaadin

I want to test my protected routes, which only admins should be able to get access to.
We want to secure these rules with tests. But when I test my protected routes, I always get a 200. Somehow even unknown Routes (like "/wregrhui") are returning me a 200 which is for me kinda weird.
My component behind a protected route I want to test:
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@RolesAllowed(value = {Role.ROLE_ADMIN})
@Route(value = "methodUsed/create", layout = CustomAppLayout.class)
public class MethodUsedEditView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {
    ...
}

And this is the test class for this component:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
@WebMvcTest(MethodUsedEditView.class)
public class AuthorizationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "USER")
    public void testAccessingWithWrongRole() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/methodUsed/create"))
               .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
}

Unfortunately all tutorials only showing the best case: If X, Y, Z, then expect 200. While I actually want to get the exact opposite. I want to trigger a 401/403 by trying to get access to a protected route with a wrong user role. I have to get anything but not a 200 ... I should get a 401 or 403.
I tried to perform as a specific user, I tried to get access to urls which aren't even defined. I always get an 200.
Because this route is protected I expect an 401 or 403

Are you using TestBench UIUnitTest product in your tests? There is demo project here: https://github.com/TatuLund/uiunittest-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/com/example/application/views/addresses/AddressesViewTest.java

You cannot test Vaadin applications with MockMvc.
If you have a subscription, you can use https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/testing/ui-unit
If you don't have a subscription use Karibu Testing
https://github.com/mvysny/karibu-testing
You can find nice examples with Karibu Testing in my OSS project:
https://github.com/72services/jtaf4/tree/develop/src/test/java/ch/jtaf/ui
